# Absolute maximum of symbolic expression in matlab

Tags: matlab

Is there any direct function for finding maximum of absolute of a symbolic function? for example

```
syms x1 x2
assume(-10<x1<10)
assume(-12<x2<8)
max(abs(x1+x2))
```

returns

```
Input arguments must be convertible to floating-point numbers.
```

as error.

Answer (score 1):

The ability to use the functions `MAX` and `MIN` for objects of class `sym` is not available in MATLAB.

To work around this issue, you could do one of the following, depending on the definition of the symbolic variables:

1. For symbolic comparisons there is no general workaround as there is no clear definition of what the result should look like. An example shows quite clearly the lack of a definition of a "good" result.

   ```
   % This code will not work
   syms x1 x2 x3 x4 x5
   X = [x1,x2,x3,x4,x5];
   max(X)
   min(X)
   % also unclear:
   x1 > x2
   x4 < x3
   ```

   If the ranges of the symbolic variables being compared are clearly separated, the function `FEVAL` can be used as follows:

   ```
   syms x positive;
   syms y positive;
   feval(symengine,'max',x,-y)
   ```

   Similarly, a comparison can be made between a symbolic variable and a double using the function `FEVAL`:

   ```
   syms x positive
   feval(symengine,'max',x,-1)
   ```

   This will return "`x`" as `x` would be always greater 0 and therefore greater `-1`.
2. If you have an array of symbolic numbers like

   ```
   X = sym([1,2,3,4]);
   ```

   then the array can be cast to type `DOUBLE` before using the function `MAX/MIN` on it. E.g.

   ```
   max(double(X))
   ```

Comment: I have edited your post so that it is better formatted in terms of code.  As you are new here, please read this guideline on how to format code fragments on Stack Overflow in order for people to better appreciate your answer and for easier digest: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks